# Flutter Send user to another screen if response is 401 or 403

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have functions witch I use to get data from the api, and the user can be logged in, but the admin can change the password of the employee, so when the user comes back to the app the besic auth token that is saved in local storage isnt the same as the one that the admin changed to since the admin changed the password, so all i need is that if there is status code such as 401 or 403 to send the user back to the log in screen. And if the response code is 500 to show like an image to come back later.

```
Future<Response> fetchWorkingLocationData() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var authorization = prefs.getString('authorization');
  var url = 'https://dev.api.wurk.skyver.co/api/v1/projects';
  basicAuth = 'Basic ' +
      base64Encode(
        utf8.encode('${phoneNumberController.text}:${passwordController.text}'),
      );
  response2 = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'authorization': authorization ?? basicAuth.toString()
    },
  );
  return response2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom logic based on the [statusCode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/HttpStatus-class.html)
So something like:

```
if (response2.statusCode == HttpStatus.unauthorized) {
  Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    'login',
  );
}
```

If you don't have context for the Navigator, check out https://medium.com/flutter-community/navigate-without-context-in-flutter-with-a-navigation-service-e6d76e880c1c

Comment: Is there a way to catch FormatException and if there is one then send the user to login screen